# transform base_link to base_laser,map,odom

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, base-link, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know the meaning of transform base_link to base_laser.

But what is the meaning of transform base_link to map?

What is the meaning of transform base_link to odom?

Because I need the meaning to set the correct value in navigation program.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10658/transform-base_link-to-base_laser,map,odom/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check out the [Coordinate Frames Convention](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html).

In a nutshell,

- `odom` to `base_link` is the position of the robot in the inertial odometric frame, as reported by some odometric sensor (like wheel encoders)
- `map` to `odom` is a correction introduced by localization or SLAM packages, to account for odometric errors.
- `map` to `base_link` is therefore the corrected pose of the robot in the inertial world frame.

These are dynamic transforms, and different components of the navigation stack are responsible for publishing them.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
So,I should make a link of (odom,base_link) and(map,odom),but not (map,base_link),right?

**Comment by [Zuhair95](https://answers.ros.org/users/87984/zuhair95/) on 2022-05-24**:
Please, how can I access /map to /base_link tfs, that generated during gmapping ? I am looking forward your suggestion.

Thanks in advance.